# Exporting multiple dataframes to one excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

On the click of a download button, I am trying to download multiple dash datatables to one excel file on different sheets. I have a callback that on a different click, performs some calculations and returns dataframes to dash datatables. I want to take those tables (after calc performed) and export to one excel file. Note: I cannot download new version of dash with dcc.download not have access to expansions. That is why I am trying to do this via pandas.

The dataframes below ('Investment_To_Gross_Impact', etc.) represent the new datatables after calcs have been performed.

```
#download to xsxl
@CAD.callback(
    Output('download', 'data'),
    Input('download', 'n_clicks'),
    Input("titleinput", "value"),
    Input('Investment_To_Gross_Impact','data'),
    Input('Investment_From_Gross_Impact','data'),
    Input('Investment_To_Assumptions','data'),
    Input('Investment_From_Assumptions','data'), 
)

def export(n_clicks, value, invto, invfrom, ato, afrom ):
    df1= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(invto)
    df2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(invfrom)
    df3= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ato)
    df4= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(afrom)
    if n_clicks>0:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(str(value)+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inv To Gross Impact')
            df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inv From Gross Impact')
            df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inv To Assumptions')
            df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inv From Assumptions')
        writer.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't realize the file was downloading into the directory where my py file is being saved.

```
def export(n_clicks, netimpact, invto, invfrom, ato, afrom, value):
    netdf= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=netimpact)
    df1= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=invto)
    df2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=invfrom)
    df3= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=ato)
    df4= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=afrom)
    filename= (str(value)+'.xlsx')
    writer= pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
    netdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Net RAF Impacts', index=False)
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inv To Gross Impact', index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inv From Gross Impact', index=False)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inv To Assumptions', index=False)
    df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Inv From Assumptions', index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try pandas `merge` to get the dataframes into one, then export that one dataframe.